# Is there a function I can use to find which UIButton was pressed and return true of false?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I created a test quiz where there would be 3 questions and you have to choose the correct button. Each button displays has an option with the correct answer. So the user is suppose to choose the correct button and in the debug area it would let know.

However it does not matter what button I click on. I get the same answer, "sucks".

Can anyone help me with this?

.........

Here is my questionBrain swift file.

```
struct Quiz {

     let userQuestions = [

        Questions(q: "2 + 2", button1: "4", button2: "6", a: "4"),
        Questions(q: "20 x 2", button1: "10", button2: "40", a: "40"),
        Questions(q: "10 - 5", button1: "3", button2: "5", a: "5")

       ]

    var questionNumber = 0



    //Check answers
    func checkAnswer(_ userAnswer: String) -> String{


        if userAnswer == userQuestions[questionNumber].a {

            return "True"
        }


        else {

            return "False"
        }

    }

}
```

Main code from my viewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var leftButtonLabel: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var rightButtonLabel: UIButton!


    var appQuiz = Quiz()


    @IBAction func userAnswerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle!
        let questionAnswer = appQuiz.checkAnswer(userAnswer)



        if userAnswer == questionAnswer {

                   print("True")
               }

               else {
                   print("sucks")
               }

        appQuiz.getNextQuestion()

        nextQuestion()

    }


    func nextQuestion(){

        headerLabel.text = appQuiz.getQuestionText()
        questionLabel.text = appQuiz.getQuestionAmount()
        leftButtonLabel.setTitle(appQuiz.getButtonText1(), for: .normal)
        rightButtonLabel.setTitle(appQuiz.getButtonText2(), for: .normal)

    }


}
```

My problem is here:

```
@IBAction func userAnswerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle!
        let questionAnswer = appQuiz.checkAnswer(userAnswer)



        if userAnswer == questionAnswer {

                   print("True")
               }

               else {
                   print("sucks")
               }

        appQuiz.getNextQuestion()

        nextQuestion()

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply compare `sender` with the button:

```
if sender === leftButtonLabel {
   // left clicked
} else {
   // right clicked
}
```

Regarding your `Questions` structure, it would be probably better to say which answer is the correct instead of repeating it:

```
Questions(q: "2 + 2", button1: "4", button2: "6", leftCorrect: true)
```

Then checking for the correct answer would be done as:

```
let leftClicked = (sender === leftButtonLabel)
let correct = (leftClicked == userQuestions[questionNumber].leftCorrect)
```

Actually, extending a bit for multiple answers, it could look like this:

```
Questions(q: "2 + 2", possibleAnswers: ["4", "6"], correctIndex: 0]
```

with

```
struct Questions {
    let q: String
    let possibleAnswers: [String]
    let correctIndex: Int
}
```

putting your buttons into an array:

```
var answerButtons: [UIButton] {
    return [leftButtonLabel, rightButtonLabel]
}
```

Setting up questions:

```
for (possibleAnswer, button) in zip(question.possibleAnswers, buttons) {
   button.setTitle(possibleAnswer, for: .normal)
}
```

And checking for correct answer:

```
let buttonIndex = buttons.index(of: sender) ?? 0
let answeredCorrectly = (question.correctIndex == buttonIndex)
```

Comment: Thank you very much... You have given me an insight that made all my problems go away.